# Convert SVG fonts to SVG shapes/images

Tags: fonts, svg

I am dealing with an SVG font. Can I extract font glyphs from these font definitions as normal SVG images and/or shapes, and use those shapes in my application? The specific SVG font I am using is [this one](https://github.com/OpenLilyPondFonts/lilyboulez.git). So basically is it possible to use svg glyphs/fonts inside another svg file by referencing them?

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. I reduced your question to a single problem that is suited for this site. I suggest that you ask your question on using this font via your operating system on [unix.se].

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, amirt, can you tell us something more about your efforts? Have you tried to open the svg files with the glyphs and copying/pasting the desired paths? What is your specific problem?

Comment: Hello, meanwhile i have found out that i need to just copy the "d" attribute of a glyph and put it into a svg element. I am not sure that this is the best correct way to do it, but it seems to work! Is it possible to use svg fonts inside another svg file?